# Confustion between different types of Spin Hall Effects (SHE)

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-hall-effect

Spin Hall Effect (SHE) is the flow of transverse spin current due to applied electric field. There are several other effects that are somehow connected with SHE, for example,

1. intrinsic SHE
2. extrinsic SHE
3. anomalous SHE
4. planner SHE
5. magnetic SHE

I am confused, what exactly is the difference between all these?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the extrinsic and intrinsic SHE:**

They describe the microscopic scattering effect that leads to charge-spin-current interconversion. I like [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.060412) very much which demoes the role of defects for spin scattering. Pt is one of the best studied materials but similar transitions between extrinsic and intrinsic SHE dominated regimes exist for all materials. The charge resistivity is a good gauge as to which regime you are in, but the threshold is different for every material.

**I have not heard the other 3 terms being used, but here is my interpretation:**

The SHE is essentially the same effect as the anomalous Hall effect (note: *not* anomalous spin Hall effect). The SHE occurs in magnetically disordered metals (e.g. Pt) and scatters spin-up and spin-down electrons in opposite directions thus producing spin current. If the metal is magnetic, e.g. Co, Fe etc., there are more electrons of one type (given by the spin polarization of the materials). As now the majority of electrons are scattered in one direction, a net charge imbalance is created causing a measurable charge voltage -> the anomalous Hall effect. So one can say that the magnetic SHE *is* the anomalous Hall effect.

**planar Hall effect**

The SHE - together with its inverse SHE - causes a phenomenon called Spin Hall Magnetoresistance (SMR). It is easier for current to travel in certain direction with respect to external magnetic field and/or magnetization. Therefore, SMR causes the conductivity of materials to become anisotropic. The "anisotropic magnetoresistance" (AMR) does the same for magnetic materials but via different physics. In any case, an anisotropic conductor will reveal a planar Hall effect, irrespective of whether this anisotropy is caused by SMR, AMR, another magnetic effect or even another non-magnetic effect (e.g. crystal structure).